# What are some of the major differences between Java 7 and Java 8?

Tags: java, upgrade

I wanted to know what makes java 8 different from java 7.
Why should/should'nt I upgrade to java 8 from java 7? Please list the differences.

Comment: Please explain the downvote!

Comment: Welcome to so .  please read [ask] before posting

Comment: Google broken again?

Answer (score 11, accepted):

There are many new features in JDK 8, including enhancements to Collections, new security features, and even additions to the Java programming language (e.g., [Lambda expressions](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/javaOO/lambdaexpressions.html)). Your best bet is to take a look at [What's New in JDK 8](http://www.oracle.com/technetwork/java/javase/8-whats-new-2157071.html) as there are too many to list cleanly here.

As for why you might not want to update immediately, here is the [Compatibility Guide for JDK 8](http://www.oracle.com/technetwork/java/javase/8-compatibility-guide-2156366.html), which lists incompatibilities between JDKs 7 and 8.

Comment: + in java 8 medium security level has been removed from java control panel, if you are using applets this will be difficulty for you